# How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS AND redirect all nonexistent subdomains to one specific domain

Tags: nginx

I already have a working configuration to redirect all non-existent subdomains to a specific domain. Now I want to add a configuration that redirects all HTTP requests to HTTPS on the same domain.

This config file does the subdomain redirects:

```
# redirect any non-existent subdomain (blah.domain.de -> domain.de)
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://domain.de$request_uri;
}
```

And this is the config I try to use for HTTP->HTTPS:

```
# redirect any HTTP request to its HTTPS address (http://domain.de/blub -> https://domain.de/blub)
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name domain.de mail.domain.de admin.domain.de;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

But this doesn't work because the default_server is defined twice. How can combine these two functions?

Do I really have to add the second config to every single subdomain config?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working in another way. I added it to every subdomains config via a SSL snippet. Every subdomain config includes the same SSL config. So I added to this config a http check:

```
if ($scheme = http ){
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
}
# ... followed by ssl config
```

And this is included in every subdomain server block config:

```
include snippets/ssl.conf;
```

It does what I want. Maybe there is another way without including it to every subdomain.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove `default_server` from the latter configuration and add every domain name to the `server_name` part.

Then you need to use `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` for the redirect statement.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get redirected from "http://mail.domain.de/" to "https://domain.de/".

Comment: True, didn't notice that. Using `$host` instead of `$server_name` like in my fixed answer should make it work.

Comment: Tero's edited answer and above comment provide the best way to do it. An if-condition isn't a good approach to handle this in Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx does not support nested if statements (it also doesn't support complex conditions).

Comment: How should this work? This default config only works for non-existent domains. So if someone requests "http://mail.osor.de" it will not work. Also return statement stops processing - rewrite will never be reached.

Comment: My bad, I haven't had my coffee yet. In this case, I am not aware of a way to do what you are asking.